# Vue Vuelidate pass validation to child and append validation rules not working

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-component, vuelidate

I have a parent component in Vue which uses a reusable date component. What I want is that the Date component retrieves the validation rules via the props from the parent and appends its own validation rules to the retrieved validation rules. However whenever I try this it does not seem to work or trigger the errors. Any tips?

Note: the validation when I pass it from the parent instead of trying to append it in the child.

I have the following setup:

Date.component.ts

```
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    },
    validation: {
      type: Object as PropType<Partial<Validation>>,
      default: (): Partial<Validation> => ({})
    },
    rules: {
      type: Object as PropType<Record<string, string>>,
      default: (): Record<string, string> => ({})
    }
  },

  emits: ['update:modelValue'],

  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const defaultDateValidation: Partial<Validation> = {
      validDate: Validators.validDateValidator
    };

    const rules = computed(() => {
      return { ...defaultDateValidation, ...props.validation };
    });

    const update = (value: string): void => {
      const isValid = isValidDate(value);

      if (isValid) {
        emit('update:modelValue', value);
      }
    };

    return {
      update,
      rules
    };
  }
});
```

Date.component.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <v-input
        v-bind="$attrs"
        ref="dref"
        :validation="rules"
        :rules="rules"
        :modelValue="modelValue"
        @update:modelValue="update"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This component is used inside my form:

// I cant show a full example:

The form.component.ts file contains the setup for vuelidate:

```
const rules = computed(() => ({
  date: {
    maxLength: Validators.maxLength(10)
  }
}));

const model = {
  date: ''
}

const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, model);
```

In the form.component.vue file I use the component as follows:

```
<VDate
   v-model="v$.date.$model"
   :validation="v$.date"
 />
```

My goal is that when I pass a maxLength validator to the date component, that it appends the validDate validation to the vuelidate object. How can I achieve this?

I have looked into Vuelidate nested validations (https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/advanced_usage.html#nested-validations), however do not seem to get them to work without it resulting in recursive loops.